# Is it possible to reinject the environment value (managedObjectContext) during runtime

Tags: core-data, swiftui, cloudkit

I inject an `NSManagedObjectContext` into my view hierarchy the following way.

```swift
@main
struct MyApp: App {
  var persistence: Persistence

  var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistence.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```

In the user settings I can switch on/off the CloudKit sync mechanism. The `viewContext` in the `Persistence` instance will be reinitialized accordingly. This is working fine. But my complete view hierarchy is still using the old `NSManagedObjectContext` instance.

Is there any way to update (reinject) the environment value or to reload the whole view hierarchy with the newly instantiated `viewContext`?

Comment: No idea if this will work, but what if you made `Persistence` be a singleton with a 'static let shared = Persistence()' and then rather than passing it in the environment, call it as an @ObservedObject in your views?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible approach - you need to make `Persistence` as `ObservableObject` and observe it in app, like

```
struct MyApp: App {
  @StateObject var persistence: Persistence = Persistence() // or whatever init neede

  ...
```

and

```
class Persistence: ObservableObject {
  @Published var container: NSPersistentContainer?

  ...
```

so whenever you change container the view context will be re-injected into `ContentView`

Comment: Ich integrated your proposal into to my app. Unfortunately, this is only half of the story. The persistence changes are propagated through the view hierarchy. But the `.environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistence.container.viewContext)` is still not updated. I added additionally `.id(persistence.persistenceContainerReloaded)` in app to trigger a full reload of the view hierarchy.